# How do you ADD banding to a gradient?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

There are a million posts on the web about removing banding but I'd like to know how to add banding. I've found some polygonal images and would like to recreate their effect.

[image]

Comment: Try choosing 2 colors which are close together. This leaves fewer integer values between them to stretch. A gradient from 0 to 255 will have 255 possible bands over 1 unit distance. A spread from 50 to 60 has only 10 values over the same unit distance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick method to add banding is reducing the color depth of an image. When choosing an optimized palette for indexed output banding will be introduced at the color steps needed to reproduce the true color RGB source.

Examples:

**RGB source**

[image]

**Indexed to 64 colors optimized palette:**

[image]